# Custom Components Listen to events from other components

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to share events between custom polymer components.

I want to append a header to every request i send. For this purpose I wanted to create a custom element.

```
<template>

</template>
<style is="em-header-inject">
</style>
<script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';

        Polymer({
            is: 'em-header-inject',

            properties: {
                listeners: {
                    'em-send-request': 'handleRequest'
                }
            },
            computeHeaders: function() {
                return {'Authorization' : 'Bearer {' +  app.accessToken + '}'};
            },
            handleRequest: function(request) {
                console.log("handling request", request);
                request.header = this.computeHeaders();
            }


        });
    })();
</script>
```

in any other component I want to do something like this

```
this.fire('em-send-request', addRiderRequest);
```

But the event listener does not see the event being fired. Is this by design or am I missing something?

Comment: Is `this` in `this.fire` a child element of `<em-header-inject>`?

Comment: No, this.fire(), is called in an other component. I added <em-header-inject> into my index.html

Comment: Events bubble from child to parent (if bubbling is not disabled for this event - enabled by default). Other elements won't be able to listen to the event. You can use https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals

Comment: Thanks I will try that right now. I think that might be what I'm looking for.